# How to set the default `assignee` to a particular user

Tags: asana

I have worked on Atlassian Jira for few years. 
I have started exploring asana for tech project management; currently, I am the only user in the project.

When I create the tasks, I have to manually select the assignee to myself. 
How can I set the default assignee to myself?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set a default for all task assignment.  Automatic task assignment depends on the context of where you create the task.

When you click the orange + button on the Asana top bar and then click to create a new task, the resulting task will automatically be assigned to you.  Also, if you are in the 'My Tasks' section of Asana, hitting 'return' will create a new task automatically assigned to you.

If you are creating tasks by hitting 'return' in a project, you can use the [keyboard shortcut](https://asana.com/guide/help/faq/shortcuts) 'Tab-M' to assign the task to you.